# Unable to get just subfolder objects from s3 aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using this function to get data from S3:

```
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3client = boto3.client('s3')
    Bucket = s3.Bucket('ais-django');
    obj = s3.Object('ais-django', 'Event/')


    list = s3client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='ais-django' ,Prefix='Event/' )  
    for s3_key in list:
         filename = s3_key['Key']
```

When I use prefix for Event folder (path is like 'ais-django/Event/') it gives abnormal output like this:

```
{
  'IsTruncated': False,
  'Prefix': 'Event/',
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'date': 'Mon, 11 Jun 2018 12:42:35 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/xml',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      'x-amz-bucket-region': 'us-east-1',
      'x-amz-request-id': '94ADDB21361252F3',
      'server': 'AmazonS3',
      'x-amz-id-2': 'IVuVQuB2V7nClm5FaX4FRbt6brS3gAiuwpERnZxknIWoZLH65LerURwmoynKW5sv37VP6FdbYho='
    },
    'RequestId': '94ADDB21361252F3',
    'RetryAttempts': 0,
    'HostId': 'IVuVQuB2V7nClm5FaX4FRbt6brS3gAiuwpERnZxknIWoZLH65LerURwmoynKW5sv37VP6FdbYho=',
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200
  },
  'MaxKeys': 1000,
  'Name': 'ais-django',
  'KeyCount': 0
}
```

while without prefix when I add like this:

```
list = s3client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='ais-django' )[Contents]
```

it gives list of all objects.

So how I can get all objects in a specific folder ?

Comment: If there is no Contents key in the dict returned from list_objects_v2() then there are zero objects matching the requested prefix. What Contents do you get from list_objects_v2() when called *without* the prefix?

Answer (score 1):

this is the way you should do it :)

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('ais-django')

for o in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Event/test-event'):
    print(o.key)
```

this is the result you will get

[image: result1]

the result contains **Event/test-event/** as there is no folder system in AWS s3 , everything is an object, hence **Event/test-event/** as well as **Event/test-event/image.jpg** are both considered as objects.

if you want only contents , i.e , image only  you can do it like this,

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('ais-django')

for o in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Event/test-event'):
    filename=o.key
    if filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        print(o.key)
```

Now in this case we are getting **Event/test-event/18342087_1323920084341024_7613721308394107132_n.jpg** as a result as we are filtering our results out and this is the only image object in my bucket right now

[image: result2]